# Error 500 while using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, internal-server-error

I can't use a sub domain in my site. It is returning as:

> error 500 , internal server error.

When I checked, I found that the problem was with my htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes

RewriteRule    ^contest/?$    contest.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^contest/(.+)/?$    contest.php?name=$1&id=htapappu    [NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^news/?$    news.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^news/(.+)/?$    news.php?newsid=$1    [NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^projects/?$    projects.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^projects/(.+)/?$    projects.php?projectid=$1    [NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^page/?$    page.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^page/(.+)/?$    page.php?feed=$1    [NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^photos/?$    photos.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^photos/(.+)/?$    photos.php?catg=$1    [NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^profile/complete/?$    complete_profile.php    [NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^profile/picture/?$    set_profile_pic.php    [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ member.php?userismnob=$1&redirect=me    [NC,L]
```

The problem is in last line.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ member.php?userismnob=$1&redirect=me    [NC,L]
```

When I remove the last two lines, There is no problem. I think it is a small problem.

Comment: What do you want these two lines to do?

Comment: @BernardoLima If user type this ( www.mysite.com/username) in address bar , The page get from  www.mysite.com/member.php?userismnob=$1&redirect=me

Comment: Are you getting 500 for `www.mysite.com/username` URL? Can you check your Apache error.log

Comment: @Abubhava : No , There is no problem in www.mysite.com/username .
check http://www.keralaphotography.org/shameel.kadannamanna

Comment: So which URL is giving you 500 error?

Comment: @anubhava admin.keralaphotography.org

Comment: So 500 is only on this domain `admin.keralaphotography.org`?

Comment: If you don’t have a `member.php` under your admin subdomain, then you should not be applying this redirect when the admin subdomain was used to access the site …

Comment: Use `error.log` and `RewriteLog`

Comment: Actually that was my suspicion too but it seems `http://admin.keralaphotography.org/member.php` does exist.

Comment: @anubhava it is exits,, I can access it... No error there.
So , I am changing my question.. 
how can i redirect http://admin.keralaphotography.org/ to http://admin.keralaphotography.org/index.php

Comment: ok posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load `index.php` by default using `DirectoryIndex` directive and then add a rule to ignore all rewrites for your subdomaon:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -Indexes    
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# ignore further rules for admin
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule    ^contest/?$    contest.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^contest/(.+)/?$    contest.php?name=$1&id=htapappu [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule    ^news/?$    news.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^news/(.+)/?$    news.php?newsid=$1    [NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^projects/?$    projects.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^projects/(.+)/?$    projects.php?projectid=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule    ^page/?$    page.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^page/(.+)/?$    page.php?feed=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule    ^photos/?$    photos.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^photos/(.+)/?$    photos.php?catg=$1    [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule    ^profile/complete/?$  complete_profile.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^profile/picture/?$   set_profile_pic.php  [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ member.php?userismnob=$1&redirect=me [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thankyou... Now it is working Perfectly.. 
Actually I am a 15 yr old boy from India.. I learned HTML, PHP , HTACCESS with help of internet only,, I want to learn more, Can you help Me ???
If you are available in facebook ... Kindly send a request to www.facebook.com/shameel.kadannamanna

Comment: Kudos to you for learning so much at this young age. I am not active on FB but you can connect with me on LinkedIn (check my profile for my LinkedIn handle).

Comment: Sure, I will connect, Thanx